# Retain text cursor position in VS2008 editor after "Break All"

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm having trouble finding a way to prevent the VS2008 debugger from automatically jumping to the currently executing line of code when I click "Break All" to edit a source file. I want to keep my editing cursor where it is in a specific method.

A possible workaround is to use Bookmarks to jump back once debugging, but with frequent breaks and large source files (and programmer multitasking) it becomes cumbersome quickly.

I'm also open to other workarounds as well, or strategic suggestions in general.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the Navigate Backward button will bring you back to where the caret was before the break.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a Microsoft Intellimouse Optical and I assumed that the back/forward buttons were the same as the Navigate buttons is VS. I was incorrect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I also have an [open source (GPL) add-in for Visual Studio 2005/2008](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/index.php?title=Tools:SamTools:Features) that binds the Navigate commands to the back/forward buttons on your mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, that's Ctrl and the minus key.

Comment: No, I don't mind. It actually looks great. I'll need to look and see how you did that.